# Создание app link Facebook android

Tags: android, facebook-api

Пытаюсь создать app link для приложения,  заполняю данную форму. На сколько я понял  нужно указать путь к активити которое запускает приложение в таком формате: `com.company.project` + путь к пакету в котором лежит главное активити, которое я указал при регистрации своего приложения в fb. Так же пробовал указывать просто пакет с активити, т.к. базовый пакет оно и так знает  но все равно ошибка таже:

```
The provided custom URL is not valid, please provide a well formed URL.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там нужно указать базовый [Deep Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) по которому можно открыть ваше приложение, если оно установлено на устройстве. Например `myappschema://mydomen/path`. Если вы такого у себя в приложении не реализовали, то указывать здесь ничего не нужно.

Comment: нет, такого я не делал Т.е. достаточно указать 'App Name' и 'Package Name' ??

Comment: Ну там же написано что это опциональное поле и его можно не указывать

Comment: Правда на сколько я понимаю весь смысл этих апп линоков как раз в том что бы по полной использовать ваши диплинки...

Comment: я просто иду по этому туториалу https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android , хочу рассылать инвайты, но про диплинки там ничего не сказано - стоит их  добавить ?

Comment: Учитывая что без них пользователи не смогут открыть ваше приложения по ссылке (ибо ссылки то такой нет), то думаю стоит)